# How to configure React Native Tools to use app.config.js instead of app.json

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo, vscode-debugger, react-native-tools

I am debugging my React Native expo application with the following `launch.json` configuration in vscode:

```json
{
  "name": "Debug in Exponent",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "type": "reactnative",
  "request": "launch",
  "platform": "exponent",
  "expoHostType": "lan",     
}
```

This is done using the [React Native Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native#configuring-expo).

However, I have a [dynamic configuration (`app.config.js`)](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/?redirected#configuration-resolution-rules) that sets up quite some environment variables etc, which is ignored by the debug configuration (which [uses `app.json` directly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native#configuring-expo)). How can I setup my `launch.json` to use the `app.config.js` instead of `app.json`?